# Guava ImmutableBiMap becomes LinkedHashMap and cause Spring autowiring mistake

Tags: java, spring, guava

I have ImmutableBiMap filled with 2 simple Spring beans.

OS: Manjaro Linux
JDK version: 1.8.0.102 Oracle
Spring version: 4.3.4.RELEASE from

```
<groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
<artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
<version>Athens-SR1</version>
```

Creating context throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [...]: Illegal arguments for constructor; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

As following screen show, when exception is throw by Spring's BeanUtil argument is a LinkedHashMap instead of BiMap.

[image]

Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class TestControl {
    private final BiMap<String, Integer> automatons;

    @Autowired
    public TestControl(BiMap<String, Integer> automatons) {
        this.automatons = automatons;
        log.info("automatons={}", automatons.keySet());
    }
}

@Configuration
public class TextContext {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                TextContext.class,
                TestControl.class
        );
        BiMap bean = context.getBean(BiMap.class);
    }

    @Bean
    BiMap<String, Integer> automatons() {
        return ImmutableBiMap.of(
                "Cellular Automaton", cellularAutomaton(),
                "Monte Carlo Automaton", monteCarloAutomaton());
    }

    @Bean
    Integer cellularAutomaton() {
       return 6;
    }

    @Bean
    Integer monteCarloAutomaton() {
       return 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: 4.3.4 RELEASE. The problem occurs when map contains spring beans. I'll try commit today all the code and give you link.

Comment: Would there be any reason for this particular bean/BiMap to be post processed by Spring / another Spring bean ? e.g. caching, transaction interceptors, AOP, post processors, ... that would operate on him ? I'd follow that path first.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I changed question to MCVE. My application is pretty complicated. I use JavaFX together with Spring, but this particular case looks like some Guava / Spring problem.

Comment: I'm able to (sort of) reproduce the error by creating classes A, B, C, D and a bean for each, and the bean method is then called to populate the BiMaps, and I have started to debug the issue. Initially it looks like a unsupported use-case or a bug.

Comment: Now we're talking. Excellent MCVE.

Comment: I was able to debug my way to the answer which is listed below, it is a sideeffect of the way maps are handled. If you look in DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans() you will see that if you autowire a (unqualified) Map into an Constructor, Spring will actually look at the valueType of the map, and find all beans of that type and return a LinkedHashMap with those values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a side effect of [how Spring handles some container types](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation).

> Even typed `Map`s can be autowired as long as the expected key type is
>   `String`. The `Map` values will contain all beans of the expected type,
>   and the keys will contain the corresponding bean names: [...]

A [`BiMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) is a `Map`.

Spring isn't trying to inject your `automatons` bean into the `TestControl`. Instead, it's trying to find all beans of type `Integer` as the values, collecting them into a `Map` (`LinkedHashMap` as implementation of choice), and associating them with their bean name as the key.

In this case, it fails because the constructor expects a `BiMap`.

One solution is to inject by name.

```
@Autowired()
public TestControl(@Qualifier(value = "automatons") BiMap<String, Integer> automatons) {
    this.automatons = automatons;
}
```

By specifying a qualifier with a name, Spring will instead try to find a bean (with the appropriate type) that's named `automatons`.

If you're not too attached to the `final` instance field, you could also inject the field with `@Resource`

```
@Resource(name = "automatons") // if you don't specify the name element, Spring will try to use the field name
private BiMap<String, Integer> automatons;
```

---

For  *reasons*, this will only work 4.3+.

> For beans that are themselves defined as a collection/map or array
>   type, `@Resource` is a fine solution, referring to the specific
>   collection or array bean by unique name. That said, as of 4.3,
>   collection/map and array types can be matched through Spring’s
>   `@Autowired` type matching algorithm as well, as long as the element
>   type information is preserved in `@Bean` return type signatures or
>   collection inheritance hierarchies. In this case, qualifier values can
>   be used to select among same-typed collections, as outlined in the
>   previous paragraph.

I would be OK with the behavior you're seeing in pre-4.3, but this does seem like a bug for `Map`. (The correct behavior occurs for `List` and array types.)

I've opened [SPR-15117](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15117) to track it, which has now been resolved (2 day turnover, wow!).

Comment: Great job!  In short collection of found beans should not be treated as distinct bean.

Comment: @MichałMielec In 4.3+, they should be, according to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a giant bug in Spring (which I doubt) this must be a human/editor error.

I have re-created a somewhat simpler example, same basics I have just used String, Integer, Long, and Boolean since I didn't have your types - this simple example it works.

LinkedHashMap is not a BiMap, so it would be a bug if it is chosen as an autowire candidate. It almost sounds like the source and compiled code is out-of-sync, have you tried to delete the build folder and rebuild?

If rebuilding does not help, the only way to solve this is good old fashioned debugging.

1. Put a breakpoint inside LinkedHashMaps constructor and see where it is constructed, does it have anything to do with your beans?
2. Set a conditional breakpoint (so you only stop if beanName.equals( "automatonTypeSettingsControl") in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver#autowireConstructor, and step through the method so you can see how spring finds the autowire candidate;
3. Make the simplest standalone example which fails, put it on Github and post a link, then some one else may be able to help you debug.

**Observation:** I have read a lot of StackOverflow post during the last month, and it looks like the average developer is not very good a debugging thirdparty code. You can actually learn a lot from debugging other peoples code, especially the spring framework code, which I find quite easy to read, considering the problem it is solving.

**Edit** This turned out to be a limitation in Spring as described in another answer. That said I ended up reproducing the error and reading trough the Spring code to find the exact code for this behavior in about 1 hour. I feel that many developers overlook debugging as a software discipline. For me it is one of the most important disciplins, since you probably spend most of your time working with code you did not write yourself.